# Connecting to MySQL through Cygwin

Tags: mysql, cygwin

I have [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) running on my desktop and can connect to the MySQL server via phpMyAdmin.  However, when I try to connect through Cygwin:

> Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysql.sock' (2)

I've tried connecting to MySQL on the same machine, my local dev server and my remote server, all failed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P <PORT> -u root -p
```

This is what worked for me. Make sure you check what is the correct port.

Check the mysqld PID with:

```
ps -sW | grep mysqld
```

And then find the PORT with:

```
netstat -nao | grep <PID>
```

Have fun!

Comment: This is a great answer I keep coming back to time and time again.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to set the default host each time w/o creating an alias as others have mentioned.

Comment: @Evan add `host=127.0.0.1` under the `[client]` section in `/etc/my.conf`. If this section doesn't exist, just create it at the end of the file and add the host line.

Answer (score -3):

you can also add the alias of itself.

```
alias mysql = 'mysql -u {user} -p{password} -h 127.0.0.1'
```